# 500 Internal Server Error when accessing admin

Tags: error-message, server, htaccess

I just get a server error when trying to access /admin, or any other URL. This is a completely new installation on a staging server. The 'Welcome' page shows OK.

I'm guessing this is a .htaccess problem, because if I remove it and change 'omitScriptNameInUrls' to false the login page shows - but unstyled. If I login I get 400 bad request.

I've looked in the web.log, but can't see anything to help there.

The hosting company is IONOS (1&1).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that `RewriteBase /` needed to be added to the htaccess

Comment: Hey, future me. Next time this happens when copying to production, this is the answer. The htaccess is in the sitename/web directory, not in the root, so you overwrote it when uploading your theme (again). Make sure it's in the gitignore.

Comment: Thanks, past me! You saved me.